# How to use a break inside a loop?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here is my code (simplified for the example, but this trigger the error also) :

```
for i = 99 to 0 by -1
    a=1
    break
```

I Have this error message :
[image]

if I use this code (without break) , the error don't trigger :

```
for i = 99 to 0 by -1
    a=1
```

if I use this code (without 'by -1'), the error don't trigger :

```
for i = 0 to 99
    a=1
    break
```

Can you help me understand what I am missing ?

NB : I use pinescript V5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this same error message. From the Pine Script v5 manual: "It is -1 when start value > end value."

Context: I wanted to evaluate from the end of a series to the start of that series.

Update: The error message went away and the code works by removing the "by -1". Pine Script detects the start value of the loop is greater than the end value and, by default, it knows to decrement by -1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The error message says the step must be greater than 0. So you can’t have “by -1” try it with “by 1” or just delete the step and it defaults to 1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you see in my question that I can use 'by-1' if I don't use break.